# Knockout Event Fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

in my MVC application im creating multiple Dropdowns by following:

```
<select data-bind="options: findGroup(1).items(),
                        optionsText: 'country',
                        optionsValue: 'id',
                        value: selectedItem(1),
                        event: { change: selectionChange }"></select>
```

the  findgroup(x) and the selectedItem(x) are global functions in my ViewModel while those are for all the dropdowns the same.

the selectedItem(x) should return the currently selected Option of the dropdown. selectedItem(x) is a function to return a computed knockout observable.

Now im facing the Problem that the selectionChange Event is fired twice. See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/LGveR/20/ 
In this example, if you Change the value of the Dropdown box, you can see that the selectionCahnge Event is fired twice.

When i leave the value: selectedItem(x) out  (and thus no computed function in the code) it doesnt: see: http://jsfiddle.net/LGveR/21/

I think that second time the Event is being fired Comes from the fact that in the computed function selectedItem(x) the observable

```
grp.selectedItem(grp.findItemByValue(value));
```

is setted.
How to prevent that the Setting of this observable leads to a "Change" Event ?

TIA,
Paul

HTML:

```
   <select data-bind="options: findGroup(1).items(),
                        optionsText: 'country',
                        optionsValue: 'id',
                        value: selectedItem(1),
                        event: { change: selectionChange }"></select> <span data-bind="text: 'aantal: ' + findGroup(1).items().length"></span>

<br /> <span data-bind="text: 'Group Selected Country: ' + findGroup(1).selectedItem().country"></span>

<br /> <span data-bind="text: 'Computed Selected Country: ' + selectedItem(1)().country"></span>

<br /> <span data-bind="text: 'after select: ' + counter()"></span>

<br />
```

Javascript:

```
 var group = function (id) {
     this.id = id;
     this.items = ko.observableArray() || {};
     this.selectedItem = ko.observable();
     this.addItem = function (data) {
         this.items.push(data);
     };
     this.findItemByValue = function (id) {
         return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.items(), function (item) {
             return item.id === id;
         });
     }
 };


 var grpItem = function (id, country) {
     this.id = id;
     this.country = country;
 };



 var ViewModel = function () {
     this.groups = ko.observableArray() || {};


     this.counter = ko.observable(0);
     this.selectionChange = function (data, event, selector, item) {

         this.counter(this.counter() + 1);
     };

     this.addGrp = function (data) {
         this.groups.push(data);
     };

     this.findGroup = function (groupId) {
         var ret = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.groups(), function (c) {
             return c.id === groupId;
         });
         return ret;
     };

     this.selectedItem = function (groupId) {
         var grp = this.findGroup(groupId);
         return ko.computed({
             read: function () {
                 return this.findGroup(groupId).selectedItem();
             },
             write: function (value) {
                 grp.selectedItem(grp.findItemByValue(value));
             }
         }, this);
     };
 };

 var vm = new ViewModel();
 var p = new group(1);
 var a = new grpItem(1, 'holland');
 var b = new grpItem(2, 'germany');
 var c = new grpItem(3, 'brasil');
 p.addItem(a);
 p.addItem(b);
 p.addItem(c);

 vm.addGrp(p);


 ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: i cant see any computed function in your code

Comment: @Jeroen, i will add the code for future use. Unfortunately in my fiddle (Chrome) im facing no Errors in the console :S...

Comment: @johnSmith , the second fiddle has no computed, to demonstrate that the data-bind value: selectedItem(x) "corrupts" the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a couple odd things in your code which results in the computed being recomputed a bunch of times. Basically, you're setting the computed value by setting an observable with a function that relies on that observable, which recomputes your computed (or something crazy like that, see http://jsfiddle.net/LGveR/25/ to see how many times read and write are being called). There are a couple simple ways you can simplify and remove this issue:

1. Remove the optionsValue from your select data-bind. This will set
   the value to the entire item in the observable array (instead of
   just the id). You can then simplify the computed write function.

   ```
       <select data-bind="options: findGroup(1).items(),
                          optionsText: 'country',
                          value: selectedItem(1),
                          event: { change: selectionChange }"></select>
   ```

   and

   ```
   this.selectedItem = function (groupId) {
        var grp = this.findGroup(groupId);
        return ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return grp.selectedItem();
            },
            write: function (value) {
                grp.selectedItem(value);
            }
        }, this);
    };
   ```

   see http://jsfiddle.net/LGveR/23/
2. Alternatively, you could remove the selectedItem on the viewmodel
   entirely, and remove the optionsValue (as in #1). Then, you only need the group observable with the following html:

   ```
       <select data-bind="options: findGroup(1).items(),
                           optionsText: 'country',
                           value: findGroup(1).selectedItem,
                           event: { change: selectionChange }"></select> 
       <span data-bind="text: 'aantal: ' + findGroup(1).items().length"></span>        
       <br /> 
       <span data-bind="text: 'Group Selected Country: ' + findGroup(1).selectedItem().country"></span>
       ...
   ```

   See http://jsfiddle.net/LGveR/24/